# WMS BBOX parameter not showing the box but whole world

Tags: mapping, openlayers, openlayers-3, wms

I am trying to call a WMS service but the BBOX parameter doesn't seem to be working. The problem is that BBOX value isn't taken into account and still the whole world is shown. My code is as follows

```js
map = new ol.Map({   target: 'map',   layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM(),name:'Map'
    }),
    new ol.layer.Image({
      name:'Fires',
      source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
        url: 'https://firms.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/wms',
        params: {'LAYERS': 'fires_viirs_24','MAP_KEY':'c25ad450306982d960f6dac44bc80059',
                 'COLORS':'127+9+9','SIZE':'10','SYMBOLS':'triangle',
                 'SRS':'EPSG:3857','WIDTH':'1024','BBOX':'18.808594,34.615127,29.047852,41.902277'}
      })
    })   ],   view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([23.8567, 38.5204]),
    zoom: 6   }) });
```

Here follows the [codepen](https://codepen.io/agristatseu/pen/qvLoEd)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some parameters are set dynamically and any values you set will be overridden.  OpenLayers sets BBOX to match the viewport.  See https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/apidoc/ol.source.ImageWMS.html

> WIDTH, HEIGHT, BBOX and CRS (SRS for WMS version < 1.3.0) will be set
>   dynamically.

You can restrict the extent with the layer's extent option:

```
 new ol.layer.Image({
      name:'Fires',
      source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
        url: 'https://firms.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/wms',
        params: {'LAYERS': 'fires_viirs_24','MAP_KEY':'c25ad450306982d960f6dac44bc80059',
                 'COLORS':'127+9+9','SIZE':'10','SYMBOLS':'triangle', VERSION: '1.1.0'
                 },
        projection:'EPSG:3857',
      }),
      extent: ol.proj.transformExtent([18.808594,34.615127,29.047852,41.902277],'EPSG:4326','EPSG:3857'),
    })
```

Comment: Simple and fast. Thank you very much!